# React native don't show error on async function

Tags: react-native, asynchronous, error-handling

I've came across to a strange behavior in react-native and async function.

This is the code, it's a simple component with a async function called by a button:

```
export default class HomeScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }


  async testError() {
    console.log('enter testError')
    console.log(object)
    console.log('finish testError')
  }

  render() {
    // console.log('HomeSCreen: ', this.props.navigation)
    return (

      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress= {this.testError}>
          <Text>TEST BUTTON</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

    )
  }
}
```

When if press TEST BUTTON in Chrome console i can't see any error and the script stops at 'enter testError'.

If i remove the async keyword from testError() the error is

```
"node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:76 object is not defined"
```

, which is correct because "object" is not declared.

Why is this happening ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Because the function is on background and it wont log the output rather it will give you possible unhandled promise rejection.

`console.log(object)`
where is object?

Comment: Ok, but why in node.js this behaviour doesn't occur ?

Comment: object is not defined. where is ur object

Comment: You didn't get the point. The idea is that in node.js it give an error but in react-native don't.

Comment: Thats what I said there are no errors thrown in async function rather there are promise rejections

Answer (score 0):

In node.js this behaviour doesn't occur.

Example: test.js

```
async function testError() {
  console.log('enter testError')
  console.log(object)
  console.log('finish testError')
}

testError()

C:\Work\projects\temp>node test.js

enter testError
(node:28820) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: object is not defined
```